# Performing several CRUD operations using one REST call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm currently developing a RESTful web service using SpringBoot framework. My problem is that I wanted to perform Update, Create and Delete operations using just one rest call. When I send a GET request, it performs nothing and no exceptions. When I send a PUT request it only performs update function only. How do i fix this.

```
@Transactional
public void someFuction(Incident i,long iid){
    // update table A        
    ir.save(i);

    // create a record in table B
    mas.addActionLogsWhenReopeningIncident(iid);

    // Delete a record in table B 
    mas.deleteAnswer(iid); 
}
```

This function is called when a REST call is recieved.

Comment: Can you post your code and highlight where the issue is ?

Comment: i have updated the question @PaulNUK

Comment: JSON Patch to your rescue: http://jsonpatch.com/

Comment: Yes. the PATH request method worked.